# Notes between two columns with multicol

Tags: pdf, margins, context, multicol, postscript

I have been working to get notes (possibly margin notes, but doesn't have to be) in between two columns of text. [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395205/two-column-document-with-annotations-between-columns) has proved useful, however it works with the `twocolumn` option for the document class and I need to use `multicol`.

Also I need the notes in a single line. The question I mentioned has the notes near where the `\marginpar` command is. I want the notes in one line, first from column 1 then from column 2 (eg. col 1 note 1, col 1 note 2, col 2 note 1, etc.). It would mean the margin notes would start at the top and end before the end of the page, that's fine.

I am aware of the `marginnotes` package, but will that solve all the problems? All I need is that the notes stay on the same page as the line they refer to, but not right next to it; so maybe margin notes aren't the way to go? I am open to other options.

In case it makes a difference, I use the `import` package to load various sections of the document.

To illustrate what I am looking for, please see [this picture](http://localchurchbiblepublishers.com/wp-content/uploads/110RL-HandSizeWMClassicOpen.jpg).

EDIT: I am currently using LaTeX, but I don't mind switching to ConTeXt (or something else) or using pure TeX if that would be better/easier/make it possible. Also if editing the PostScript or PDF output would achieve the desired results, I'm open for that too. In short, I'm not too opinionated on the *how*, just so long as it works.